# UIImageView Clear Background on Areas Picture Doesn't Cover

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have a rotating set of pictures in my app, and some of the pictures are not the exact size or ratio for my UIImageView. I'd like to have it so that the areas of the image view that aren't taken up by the picture just stay transparent, but I'm having difficulties. Here is what I have tried so far, but it stays black on the sides around the pictures.

```
_imageView = [UIImageView new];
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    _imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _imageView.opaque = NO;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
```

Comment: This may end up confusing you: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` so don't do that. What color is being shown in the portion of your imageView that should be clear?

Comment: Did you try _imageView.opaque = YES;

Comment: @DonMag it is showing black behind it.

Comment: @user717452 - OK... What is the background color of the view (you had it set to clear, which may be causing the issue). If you set `_imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` do you see red where you're expecting it to be clear?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I do see red

Comment: @user717452 - OK - you see red... what's the color of the view now? Is it still set to clear? If so, you need to explain what you're trying to do by setting `self.view` background to clear.

Comment: It's a view controller with a page controller sitting on top of it. The page controller holds the image view. I want only the background of the parent view controller showing behind the image, as now, it shows a big rectangular section of black if the image doesn't take up the full view of the image view.

Comment: @user717452 - you have to provide complete details about what you're doing if you want to get help. Please review [ask].